# excel content - remove content from the cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Greeting Dear All,

Would be happy to get help for the same.

Here is a Name of the client in the 1st cell
and name and address together in 2nd cell..

in 3rd cell i want result with just address.

In short - its like search the content of 1st cell and delete from 2nd cell.

Thanks a lot to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE([2nd cell], [1st cell], "")
```